# "less than $+\infty$" is not bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis

This is an exercise in my textbook. I am puzzled that since $f$ is less than $+\infty$ on $E$, doesn't it already means $f$ is bounded above? Why we still need to show it?

[image]

Comment: Bounded above means there is a real number $M$ such that $f(x) < M$ for all $x \in E$.  Just because $f$ always takes values $< +\infty$ doesn't mean that the maximum value of $f$ is finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, functions in your book are considered to have codomain $[-\infty,+\infty]$, the **extended real numbers** ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)).

Thus, for example the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ defined by $f(x)=x$ is unbounded but still $f(x)<+\infty$ everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

A function is bounded if there exists $M\in\mathbb R$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x$. Unbounded functions (for which this condition does not hold) just need to grow without bound, they don't need to ever actually reach infinity. Even continuous functions may be unbounded (consider $f(x)=x$), but not on a compact set, as this question suggests.

Answer (score 2):

A counter-example make things clearer. On $[0,1]$, take the function $f$ that equals $0$ at any irrational number, and maps any rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ to $q$. Then $f(x)$ is finite for any $x\in[0,1]$, but $f(x)$ is far from being bounded on $[0,1]$.